# Angular Material DragDrop in Table w/Expandable Rows loses expandable sync on all rows dragged over

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, angular-cdk-drag-drop, expandable-table

I've modified the Angular Material Stackblitz to show my issue. It appears that cdkDragDrop is modifying the CSS of the rows the dragged list item goes over and then takes a few clicks of the expand/collapse button to re-sync. The rows that did not get dragged over are unaffected and functional. Is there a way to prevent the expandDetail from going out of sync?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yboiky-yras19?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only did one change in the given stackblitz example - [click here to see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yboiky-2zudlw?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.ts)

you need to change the value of height. so you just need to remove * and give proper CSS values like auto, inherit, some px, some percent.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'table-expandable-rows-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-expandable-rows-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-expandable-rows-example.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: 'auto' })), //did change here
      transition(
        'expanded <=> collapsed',
        animate('250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
      ),
    ]),
  ],
})
```